# Write a Java program that finds the second minimum of the absolute values of three numbers

Tags: java, integer, minimum

I try to find the second minimum (2nd smallest) value. I find out sometimes my code work with a positive value if I have a negative value. The output will mess up.

```
    int num1, num2, num3, minVal, secondMinVal;
    System.out.print("Ener three integer numbers: ");
    num1 = input.nextInt();
    num2 = input.nextInt();
    num3 = input.nextInt();

    minVal = num1;
    if (num2 < num1 && num2 < num3)
        num2 = minVal;
    else if (num3 < num1 && num3 < num2)
        num3 = minVal;
    System.out.println("The minimum of the absolute values of the entered numbers is " + Math.abs(minVal));

    secondMinVal = num1;
    if (num2 > num1 && num2 < num3)
        num2 = secondMinVal;
    else if (num3 > num1 && num3 < num2)
        num3 = secondMinVal;
    System.out.println("The second minimum value is " + secondMinVal);
```

---

I try to run with 7, -3, and 10 and the output will look like this:

```
Ener three integer numbers: 3 -1 10
The minimum of the absolute values of the entered numbers is 3
The second minimum value is 3
```

Comment: `num2 = minVal` is not the same as `minVal = num2` so you never update `minVal`, same for `secondMinVal`

Answer (score 1):

To assign a new value to the "minVal" variable, instead of

```
num2 = minVal;
```

you should use

```
minVal = num2;
```

The value of the variable which is to the right of the assignment operator "=" is assigned to the variable to the left of the assignment operator (for integer variables).

This logic applies to any integer variables ("secondMinVal", for example).

Answer (score 0):

```
    int num1, num2, num3, minVal, secondMinVal;
    System.out.print("Ener three integer numbers: ");
    num1 = input.nextInt();
    num2 = input.nextInt();
    num3 = input.nextInt();

    if(num1 < num2 && num1 < num3)
        minVal = num1;
    else if (num2 < num3)
        minVal = num2;
    else
        minVal = num3;
    System.out.println("The minimum of the absolute values of the entered numbers is " + Math.abs(minVal));

    secondMinVal = num1;
    if (num2 > num1 && num2 < num3)
        num2 = secondMinVal;
    else if (num3 > num1 && num3 < num2)
        num3 = secondMinVal;
    System.out.println("The second minimum value is " + secondMinVal);
```

I think I just answer my question hahaha hope this can help anyone.

Comment: Better. You still are not there. When I enter 2, 5 and 7, the output is `The minimum of the absolute values of the entered numbers is 2
The second minimum value is 2`.

Answer (score 0):

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MinOfThree {
     public static void main(String[] args){
          Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

          System.out.print("Enter first integer:");
          int firstNumber = sc.nextInt();
          System.out.print("Enter second integer:");
          int secondNumber = sc.nextInt();
          System.out.print("Enter third integer:");
          int thirdNumber = sc.nextInt();

          int smallest = firstNumber;
          if (secondNumber < smallest) {
               smallest = secondNumber;
          }
          if (thirdNumber < smallest) {
               smallest = thirdNumber;
          }
     
          System.out.print(smallest + " is the smallest integer");
     }
}
```

Comment: Review:
1. Use meaningful variable names from `a` to `firstNumber`, etc \n
2. Follow standards to name classes `minofthree` to `MinOfThree`
3. Refactor the algorithm to keep track of smallest variable